# How to use Python decorator to call at the end of exception only

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to write a decorator that will be used on any methods and make some particular action at the end of exception handling of any methods, I have tried the below approach it is working partially. Currently, it's executing the exception inside my decorator `handle_exception` method only but not executing from the `my_method` exception block, but I want to execute the `handle_exception` decorator exception block as well as `my_method` execution block is executed along with this and also I want to capture the *args and **kwargs of the original method

```
def handle_exception(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as ex:
            exception_report = {
                "event": {
                    "method": func.__name__,
                    "message": str(ex),
                    "args": args,
                    "kwargs": kwargs
                }
            }
            print('exception_report ', exception_report)

    return wrapper


@handle_exception
def my_method(a, b):
    try:
        print('Tried successfully')
        raise Exception('Error')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error from my_method', str(ex))
```

So in the end what I wanted to achieve is to gather all info about the exception, So what I am excepting is
print('Error from my_method', str(ex)) should be executed as usual and print('exception_report ', exception_report) should be called

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-raise the exception so that it can be caught again.

```
@handle_exception
def my_method(a, b):
    try:
        print('Tried successfully')
        raise Exception('Error')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error from my_method', str(ex))
        raise
```

A key tenet of exception handling is that catching an exception means you know how to handle it *now*, and it won't be propagated higher in the call stack unless you do so explicitly.

Comment: My silliness, Thanks for pointing out, I just wanted to intercept all the exceptions and create a report. Do you suggest to me something other than Decorator?

Comment: The decorator is fine. The question is why you need or want to report on an exception that the function has otherwise said is handled. (A handled exception is, for all practical purposes, indistinguishable from a nonexistent exception to the outside observer (which is what the decorator is.)

Comment: Thanks @chepner, My scenario is I wanted to add a logger whenever a block reaches except block and I want to format and I didn't want to add a logger in all except blocks in all methods, instead, I wanted to create a generic decorator to do this operation :)